# EntityFramework 7 and Unique constraint (Data Annotations or Fluid)

Tags: unique-constraint, entity-framework-core

I have been searching the net for a way to create a unique constraint using code first with data annotion or with the Fluid API for Entityframework 7.. is this not implemented yet or how come I cant find any information regarding this?
Any ideas of how to create such a constraint using code first and EF7?
Is there anyway to in the end of my OnModelCreating to execute a SQL-script to "manually" create the constraint while Im waiting for a more "solid" way of doing this?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Alternate keys:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasAlternateKey(c => c.LicensePlate);
    }
```

They are enforced via Unique indexes is SQL Server, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this using the fluent API, I haven't found a DataAnnotation yet though.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityClass>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Index).IsUnique();
        });
    }
```